# Adicionar dias à uma data

Tags: php, data, datetime

Preciso somar mais 2 dias em uma data vinda de uma variável.

Estou fazendo desta forma mas não está funcionando.

```
$data = '17/11/2014';
echo date($data, strtotime("+2 days"));
```

Comment: Pessoal, já consegui fazer oque eu queria.
Vou deixar o código aqui para que outras pessoas possam utilizar.

$data = "20-10-2014";

echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+2 days",strtotime($data)));

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 34):

já consegui fazer o que eu queria.
Vou deixar o código aqui para que outras pessoas possam utilizar.

```
$data = "20-10-2014"; 
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+2 days",strtotime($data)));
```

Answer (score 14):

Seu problema está no uso do [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php). Você precisa dizer em cima do que quer somar 2 dias. Você estava apenas somando 2 dias à nada. Além disto você precisa especificar em que formato quer a nova data para não correr o risco de sair de uma forma indesejada.

```
$data = "17/11/2014";
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime($data. ' + 2 days'));
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/J4SRc5). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/mgkiyrzq-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/PHP/Date/SumDays.php).

Comment: Amigo, obrigado.

Answer (score 13):

Outra forma de realizar essa tarefa é utlizar a classe [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) e passar o período a ser adicionado a data, ele é especificado no construtor de [DateInterval](http://php.net/manual/en/dateinterval.construct.php), deve iniciar com `P` (de periodo) e seguido de um número por último a unidade:

```
Y | Ano
M | Mês
D | Dias
W | Semanas
H | Horas
M | Minutos
S | Segundos
```

Note que mês e minuto usam a mesma letra `M`. Para que o *parse* seja feito de maneira correta a(s) maior(es) unidade(s) devem estar a esquerda.

Para valores que contenham horas, minutos ou segundos deve-se utilizar a letra `T` para sinalizar esse trecho.

---

```
<?php

$data = '17/11/2014';

$data = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $data);
$data->add(new DateInterval('P2D')); // 2 dias
echo $data->format('d/m/Y');
```

[**Exemplo**](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/9jhu-y5fa)

Comment: Amigo, obrigado. Vou fazer dessa forma que você passou.

Comment: @LucasWilliam, se a versão do seu php for a 5.3 ou superior prefira usar a classe DateTime, caso contrario use as funções, date, strtotime etc.