# Como calcular o tempo de cada ano entre duas datas?

Tags: php, data

Preciso pegar duas datas e calcular o período de tempo **de cada ano isoladamente**. Por exemplo: entre as datas `12/06/2012` e `12/06/2017` a saída correta seria:

```
2012 = 5 meses e 12 dias
2013 = 12 meses
2014 = 12 meses
2015 = 12 meses
2016 = 12 meses
2017 = 5 meses e 12 dias
```

Para encontrar o tempo total entre duas datas faço assim:

```
$inicio = strtotime(12-01-2012); // transformando em time
$fim = strtotime(12-06-2017); // transformando em time
$intervalo = $fim - $inicio;
```

E então é só converter e tal:

```
$dias = floor($intervalo / (60 * 60 * 24));
```

Mas daí pra pegar isoladamente o período de cada ano não estou conseguindo imaginar como fazer. Pensei em comparar as datas, e então criar pra cada ano um calculo diferente (repetindo tudo...), mas deve existir uma forma mais simples... Alguma ideia?

Comment: mas pelo que entendi vc só precisa calcular o período do primeiro e ultimo ano, os outros vão ser todos 12 meses, não?

Comment: se for em dias tem que calcular todos os periodos

Comment: Mas pelo que ele apresentou como saída correta seriam em meses, sendo assim não importa se um mês teve 28 ou 31 dias, fechou é mês e um ano 12 meses

Comment: tem residuos em dias

Comment: Mas apenas no primeiro e ultimo, sendo assim só precisaria do `12-01-2012 - 01-01-2012` e do `12-06-2017 - 01-01-2017` os outros seriam 12 meses completos sem nenhum residuo

Comment: essa saida para 2012 não está certa, 2012 = 5 meses e 12 dias, veja que de JULHO até o fim do ano já são 6 meses e ainda tem os dias de junho

Comment: Não sei se você poderia utilizar alguma lib, mas essa te ajudaria muito: https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/132

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**exemplo - ideone**](https://ideone.com/ikkuVq)

```
$date1 = "12/06/2012";
$date1 = str_replace("/", "-", $date1);
// data americana
$dateInicio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));

$date2 = "12/06/2017";
$date2 = str_replace("/", "-", $date2);
// data americana
$dateFim =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2));

$time1=strtotime($date1);
// ano data inicial
$year1=date("Y",$time1);

$time2=strtotime($date2);
// ano data final
$year2=date("Y",$time2);

$difAno=$year2-$year1;
// se a diferença em anos for maior que 0 calculamos ano inicial e final
if ($difAno>0){
    // para ano inicial
    $fim = ($year1."-12-31");
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($dateInicio);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($fim);
    $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
    echo "Ano: ".($year1)." - ";
    echo $interval->format('%m Meses %d dias');

    echo "<br>";

    // para ano final
    $inicio = ($year2."-01-01");
    $datetime1 = new DateTime($inicio);
    $datetime2 = new DateTime($dateFim);
    $interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
    echo "Ano: ".($year2)." - ";
    echo $interval->format('%m Meses %d dias');

    echo "<br>";

}

// se a diferença entre os anos for maior que 1 fazemos um loop para calcular os demais
if ($difAno>1){
    for ($x = 1; $x <= $difAno-1; $x++) {

        echo "Ano: ".($year1+$x)." - ";
        echo date("z", mktime(0,0,0,12,31,($year1+$x))) + 1;
        echo " = 12 meses <br>";

    }
}
```

- Se utilizarmos este formato de `dd-mm-yyyy` teremos erros, portanto utilizamos a função `date()` que retorna datas em PHP no formato que você quiser. [**date()**](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)
- [$interval->format](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/dateinterval.format.php) - Formata um intervalo.

> A “Era Unix” começou dia 1º de Janeiro de 1970, e graças a ela, podemos efetuar cálculos precisos de data. A função  [**mktime()**](https://secure.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.mktime.php) retorna o total de segundos que se passaram desde o começo da Era Unix. A função [**date()**](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.date.php)  pode formatar datas baseadas na Era Unix!

### Conforme comentário do autor da pergunta

`é que preciso incluir o dia final`

basta incluir no código a seguinte linha

`$dateFim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateFim. ' + 1 days'));`

Então teremos como resultado [**no ideone**](https://ideone.com/0LvYj3)

```
    $dateFim ="";

    $date1 = "12/06/2012";
    $date1 = str_replace("/", "-", $date1);
    // data americana
    $dateInicio = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date1));

    $date2 = "12/06/2017";
    $date2 = str_replace("/", "-", $date2);
    // data americana
    $dateFim =  date('Y-m-d', strtotime($date2));
    $dateFim = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($dateFim. ' + 1 days'));

    $time1=strtotime($date1);
    // ano data inicial
    $year1=date("Y",$time1);

    $time2=strtotime($date2);
    // ano data final
    $year2=date("Y",$time2);

    $difAno=$year2-$year1;
    // se a diferença em anos for maior que 0 calculamos ano inicial e final
    if ($difAno>0){
        // para ano inicial
        $fim = ($year1."-12-31");
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($dateInicio);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($fim);
        $interval = $datetime1->diff($datetime2);
        echo "Ano: ".($year1)." - ";
        echo $interval->format('%m Meses %d dias');

        echo "<br>";

        // para ano final
        $inicio = ($year2."-01-01");
        $datetime1 = new DateTime($inicio);
        $datetime2 = new DateTime($dateFim);
        $interval = $datetime2->diff($datetime1);
        echo "Ano: ".($year2)." - ";
        echo $interval->format('%m Meses %d dias');

        echo "<br>";

    }

    // se a diferença entre os anos for maior que 1 fazemos um loop para calcular os demais
    if ($difAno>1){
        for ($x = 1; $x <= $difAno-1; $x++) {

            echo "Ano: ".($year1+$x)." - ";
            echo date("z", mktime(0,0,0,12,31,($year1+$x))) + 1;
            echo " = 12 meses <br>";

        }
    }
```

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo Leo! Ficou bem legal, vou testar melhor amanhã, mas por enquanto fica meu +1. Valeu mesmo!

Comment: Fiz uma pequena correção em for ($x = 1; $x <= $difAno-1; $x++) {.. assim não itera o ultimo ano que já tinha sido calculado anteriormente

Comment: Então, fiz uns testes aqui e ficou muito bom mesmo, ainda estou modificando algumas coisas e testando, mas já estou marcando como resolvida aqui. Só fiz um pequeno ajuste na data final, porque tem que pegar do início do ano até a data final, então ficou assim `$fim = ($year2."-01-01");`. Fica faltando um dia no resultado ( dá 5 meses e 11 dias, e eu queria incluir o dia final), mas agora são apenas alguns detalhes... valeu mesmo, vou até shipar uma recompensa quando der o tempo mínimo... Abraços.

Comment: @gustavox calculadora online de 01-01-2017 a 12-06-2017 dá 05 e 11 veja http://pt.calcuworld.com/calendarios/calculadora-de-tempo-entre-duas-datas/

Comment: Hehehe, gran bobeira no periodo final, editei a resposta // para ano final

Comment: Então Leo, sobre os 11 dias, é que preciso incluir o dia final, então seguindo [esta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40731/adicionar-dias-%C3%A0-uma-data) do @rray fiz `$datetime->add(new DateInterval('P1D'));` e beleza. A data em si fica 'errada', mas como uso ela apenas pra este cálculo então não tem problema, o importante é o resultado... Valeu mesmo, ajudou bastante.

Comment: @gustavox editei a resposta somando 1 dia na data final

Answer (score 2):

Bom pelo que entendi vc precisaria calcular apenas o primeiro e ultimo ano pois os outros seria desperdício visto que o resultado é previsto.

Mas se insiste, joga os anos em um array então executa um foreach com o cálculo, não testei se seu cálculo esta certo mas pressupondo que esteja acho q a lógica é mais ou menos essa:

```
// Faz uma função para preencher o array com os anos entre o menor e o maior.. 
$anos = array(02-06-2012,01-01-2013,01-01-2014,01-01-2015,01-01-2016,01-01-2017,12-06-2017)

// Outra função pra atribuir o ano do menor ao inicio
$inicio = strtotime(01-01-2012);

foreach($anos as $ano){
    $fim = strtotime($ano);
    $intervalo = $fim - $inicio;
    //Aqui não sei se quer imprimir ou oq, mas coloca um array pra guardar ou imprime
    $dias = floor($intervalo / (60 * 60 * 24)); 
    $inicio = $fim;
}
```

Comment: Mateus, não tá dando certo, os resultados são sempre 0 pra `echo $dias`, acho que porque está usando a data no padrão dd/mm/yyyy mas ajudou aqui a clarear as ideias, fica meu +1. Valeu.