# Imprimir datas 15 dias para frente apartir de uma data de início

Tags: php, data

Tenho esse código que imprimi as datas estipulando o início e o fim entre elas:

Como eu faria para o sistema calcular 15 dias após o **$dateStart**?

Por exemplo:

Se a data início fosse essa  **$dateStart=05/11/2018** o sistema já estipulasse a data final somando os 15 dias para ficar **$dateEnd=19/11/2018**

```
//Star date
    $dateStart      = '05/11/2018';
    $dateStart      = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', substr($dateStart, 0, 10)))).substr($dateStart, 10);
    $dateStart      = new DateTime($dateStart);

    //End date
    $dateEnd        = '25/04/2013';
    $dateEnd        = implode('-', array_reverse(explode('/', substr($dateEnd, 0, 10)))).substr($dateEnd, 10);
    $dateEnd        = new DateTime($dateEnd);

    //Prints days according to the interval
    $dateRange = array();
    while($dateStart <= $dateEnd){
        $dateRange[] = $dateStart->format('Y-m-d');
        $dateStart = $dateStart->modify('+1day');
    }
 foreach ($dateRange as $value) {

     echo $value;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Com strtotime você consegue adicionar o que quiser, veja exemplo abaixo:

```
$data = "20-10-2014"; 
echo date('d/m/Y', strtotime("+2 days",strtotime($data)));
```

Este exemplo foi retirado de outro post sobre o assunto: [Adicionar dias à uma data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40731/adicionar-dias-%C3%A0-uma-data)