# Soma com datas e strtotime no PHP

Tags: php, data, strtotime

Nesse pequeno script de um sistema de atendimento, guardo o início do atendimento (campo `DATETIME` no banco) e o prazo estimado de seu fim (campo `TIME` no banco).

Vejam:

```
$d1 = "2019-09-23 12:30:00"; // Data e hora que o atendimento começou
$d2 = "01:00:00"; // Tempo esperado para finalizar o atendimento

$teste = strtotime($d1) + strtotime($d2);
echo date("d/m/Y H:i:s", $teste); // Imprime -> 25/05/2069 10:30:00
```

O resultado esperado deveria ser `23/09/2019 13:30:00`, porém dá o resultado impresso acima.

Por quê?

Comment: Acho que essa função do php pode te ajduar: https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.add.php

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Adicionar dias à uma data](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/40731/adicionar-dias-%c3%a0-uma-data)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Você está confundindo datas e horas com durações. Considere essas duas frases:

- o filme começa às duas horas da tarde
- o filme durou duas horas

Na primeira, "duas horas" refere-se a um horário: a um momento específico do dia. Na segunda, "duas horas" refere-se à duração: a quantidade de tempo, sem relação com um horário específico (não diz que horas começou nem terminou, só diz quanto tempo dura).

O que pode confundir é que ambos usam as mesmas palavras ("horas", "minutos", etc), mas são conceitos diferentes. Uma data representa um ponto específico de um calendário (dia, mês e ano), e um horário representa um momento específico de um dia. Já uma duração é apenas uma quantidade de tempo, e não está associada com um instante específico.

---

Dito isso, `strtotime('01:00:00')` cria uma data (não uma duração) referente ao dia de hoje, com o horário setado para 1 da manhã:

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('01:00:00')); // 2019-09-03 01:00:00
```

<sup>*Na verdade `strtotime` retorna o [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) correspondente à data acima, usando o timezone default que está configurado no PHP.*</sup>

Se quer somar horas a uma data, você pode usar os [formatos especiais](https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php) que são aceitos por [`strtotime`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php), que permite adicionar durações a uma data/hora, como por exemplo `+ X hours` para somar X horas. No caso, sua string que corresponde à duração tem hora, minuto e segundo, então ficaria algo assim:

```
$data = '2019-09-23 12:30:00';
$duracao = '01:00:00';
$v = explode(':', $duracao);
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime("{$data} + {$v[0]} hours {$v[1]} minutes {$v[2]} seconds"));
```

Eu uso [`explode`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) para quebrar a string em horas, minutos e segundos (os valores ficam no array `$v`). Em seguida, eu monto a string correspondente, contendo a data e usando a sintaxe `+ duracao` para somar a duração à data.

A saída é:

```
23/09/2019 13:30:00
```

Se bem que, como `strtotime` retorna o timestamp em segundos, bastaria converter a duração em uma quantidade total de segundos e somar ao resultado de `strtotime`:

```
$data = '2019-09-23 12:30:00';
$duracao = '01:00:00';
list($h, $m, $s) = explode(':', $duracao);
echo date('d/m/Y H:i:s', strtotime($data) + $s + ($m * 60) + ($h * 3600));
```

Comment: Sua reposta foi ideal, pois você respondeu o que eu perguntei: "O porquê". Obrigado!