# Somar datas com php

Tags: php

Eu tenho que fazer o seguinte:

Em meu código tenho 3 inputs, sendo eles:

```
Data de Início: <input type="text" class="datepicker" name="inicio">

<input type="hidden" class="datepicker" name="exp_45">

<input type="hidden" class="datepicker" name="exp_90">
```

Como podem ver dois deles são do tipo `hidden`, estou tentando fazer o seguinte:

Quando a pessoa enviar a data do input "inicio", os outros dois inputs somarem automaticamente 45 e 90 dias, sem que a pessoa tenha que calcular manualmente as datas, assim inserindo no banco de dados os valores correspondentes!
Já tentei fazer com `DateTime` porém sem sucesso... alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Sua pergunta mistura coisas diferentes. Se você realmente quer dois inputs hidden no seu html que serão atualizados conforme o usuário escolher uma data, você precisa fazer esses cálculos do lado do cliente, e não do servidor -- portanto, isso seria feito com javascript ou outra linguagem de script. Mas essa é uma ideia ruim, pois usuários com algum conhecimento podem alterar o valor dos inputs invisíveis. O PHP não teria a utilidade que você pretende no cenário que você descreveu.

Comment: Por outro lado, você pode não colocar os inputs escondidos (apenas o seletor de data) e, no seu backend, fazer o cálculo das outras duas datas (nesse caso, sim, usando PHP).

Comment: Entendi... Por agora os inputs não estão tendo utilidade mesmo, coloquei mais para entendimento geral! Como eu poderia fazer isso com php? Quer que eu poste mais algum trecho do código?

Comment: Você vai para o endpoint que recebe os dados desse formulário. E, a partir da data submetida, você consegue fazer a soma dessa forma: http://www.mauricioprogramador.com.br/posts/somar-ou-subtrair-dias-de-uma-data-com-php/

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/40731/112052